# Make static method Method<MyClass<T>> is not possible b Method<T> is possible but giving wrong data

Tags: c#, generics

This method compiles:

```
public static class ControllerExtensions
{

    public static IActionResult NoContentResult<T>(this ControllerBase controller, DomainResult<T> result)
    {
        var response = new ObjectResult(new { result.ErrorReason, result.Error });
        response.StatusCode = 204;
        return new ObjectResult(response);
   }
}
```

Why does this constraint not work at compile time?

```
 public static class ControllerExtensions
    {

        public static IActionResult NoContentResult<DomainResult<T>>(this ControllerBase controller, DomainResult<T> result)
        {
            var response = new ObjectResult(new { result.ErrorReason, result.Error });
            response.StatusCode = 204;
            return new ObjectResult(response);
       }
    }
```

at runtime you see the whole data is moved down an object level:
the top level has no ErrorReason but the bottom level has it. Its just on the wrong level :S

[image]

Comment: `NoContentResult<DomainResult<T>>` - why would you _want_ this? The first snippet looks just fine?

Comment: Also mind that in both snippets, you set an `ObjectResult` _into_ another `ObjectResult`... I guess instead of `return new ObjectResult(response);` you should just do `return response;`

Comment: Yes that was stupid copy/paste error on my side with return response. Thx for that. Now I have the correct hierarchy. Ok in the parameter of the method should have been T and not  DomainResult<T> result. NOW it works!

Comment: Because the language was designed this way. Generic methods/types accept generic type parameters (one - `T` in the first case), `DomainResult<T>` is not a valid generic type parameter name (in the second method).

Comment: In `NoContentResult<DomainResult<T>>()`, `DomainResult<T>` is not a valid [generic type parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-type-parameters). [Constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters) are specified with the `where` keyword. Generics are not composition. The version of the method that compiles is explicitly creating nested `ObjectResult`s.